# How to Find code references and/or break references?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible in visual studios 2010 or 2013 to visualize or find all code references to objects or classes.

For example, my application loads and unloads many panes into a docking control. I'm finding that when my panes are unloaded some of them never get disposed due to references. At times I have so many references to properties in my docking panes that it's easy too lose track of them.

Or is it a simple case of coding pane = null to break the references?

Many thanks for your time

Comment: did you try with **F12** ?

Comment: Will shift + F12 work for you? More details here: http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx

Comment: Guys, from the question, he's not asking how to go to declarations, he's asking how to dispose resources. The first few words in the title are not the whole question.

Comment: yes you can set them to `null` and let GarbageCollector cleanit up on behalf of you.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi But that implies that he knows everywhere that the object is referenced, which he doesn't, which is why he's asking for help.  He wants some effective way of finding out where all an object is referenced.